# Google Charts: Line Chart hAxis Labels centered

Tags: javascript, date, google-visualization, linechart

I'm working with the line chart of Google Charts and put together the following example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epJqaX

As you can see, all data points have a date, a value1 and a value 2.

At the moment I only use this code for the `hAxis`:

```
hAxis: {
  format: 'MMMM',
  ticks: dateTicks,
}
```

Now the labels on the `hAxis` are always centered under the vertical line, but I want them to be centered over the according month as illustrated in the following picture:

[image]

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer (semirturgay) is in the right direction, however there are some serious problems :

- It does not work, it should at least be wrapped into a `ready` event
- It does not take care of localization. For example, when I run the code provided by OP the months is translated to "januar", "februar" etc because I am located in Denmark. It is not wise compare hardcoded strings with google visualization localized formatted values, it *will* fail.
- It is using jQuery

Here is a working vanilla solution using google visualizations own format methods, that also is easy to change if the format of the `date` needs to be changed (just change the `DateFormat({pattern: 'MMMM'})` to whatever value of `hAxis` : `format`) :

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
   var indent = 120,
       texts = document.querySelectorAll('text'),
       formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMMM'});

   function indentText(month) {
       for (var t=0;t<texts.length;t++) {
          if (texts[t].textContent == month) {
             texts[t].setAttribute('x', parseInt(texts[t].getAttribute('x'))+indent);
             return;
          }    
       }    
   }    
   for (var i=0;i<dateTicks.length;i++) {
       indentText(formatter.formatValue(dateTicks[i]));
   }          
})
```

Has moved the codepen code to a fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/no4ztpuc/**

Comment: Thank you @davidkonrad, thats exactly what I needed - great explanation!